# What are some of the Major themes associated with God's Flood recounted in Genesis 6-9?

Tags: genesis, sin, noah, layers-of-meaning, flood

Genesis 6:5-18 seems to suggests that God saw man's wickedness, and decides to only allow a relatively good man named Noah, and his family, but then destroy all others belonging to mankind.

Genesis 6:5-8, 17-18 ([NASB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%206%3A5-18&version=NASB1995))

> 5 Then the Lord saw that the wickedness of man was great on the earth,
> and that every intent of the thoughts of his heart was only evil
> continually. 6 The Lord was sorry that He had made man on the earth,
> and He was grieved in His heart. 7 The Lord said, “I will blot out
> man whom I have created from the face of the land, from man to animals
> to creeping things and to birds of the sky; for I am sorry that I
> have made them.” 8 But Noah found favor in the eyes of the Lord.
> ...
> 17 Behold, I, even I am bringing the
> flood of water upon the earth, to destroy all flesh in which is the
> breath of life, from under heaven; everything that is on the earth
> shall perish. 18 But I will establish My covenant with you; and you
> shall enter the ark—you and your sons and your wife, and your sons’
> wives with you.

However, we see mankind's sin shows up again in the Genesis 9:20-25.

Genesis 9:20-25 ([NASB](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%209%3A20-25&version=NASB1995))

> 20 Then Noah began farming and planted a vineyard. 21 He drank of
> the wine and became drunk, and uncovered himself inside his tent. 22
> Ham, the father of Canaan, saw the nakedness of his father, and told
> his two brothers outside. 23 But Shem and Japheth took a garment and
> laid it upon both their shoulders and walked backward and covered the
> nakedness of their father; and their faces were turned away, so
> that they did not see their father’s nakedness. 24 When Noah awoke
> from his wine, he knew what his youngest son had done to him. 25 So he
> said,
>
> “Cursed be Canaan; A servant of servants He shall be to his
> brothers.”

It seems that the reason of Genesis 6 returned in Genesis 9. Therefore, what wass the reason for God's flood?

Comment: The central matter in the flood is the withdrawing of God's Spirit (Gen 6:3, cf Gen 1:2) resulting in the undoing of creation and returning of waters to the world.  A series of events in the reverse order of creation week.

Comment: I'm a little confused - the headline question is about identifying themes, but the body of the text asks a question about what the reason for the Flood was. Which question are you asking?

Comment: Also not 100% sure about whether the scope of 'what are the major themes...' is a good fit, as it's highly subjective, and it can be difficult to determine broader text-level themes from narrowly defined passages. From your question body, is it fair to say that the question isn't really about themes at all, but is rather just a simple contradiction question asking what the real reason for the Flood was?

Answer (score 1):

God was so grieved in his heart to see the effects of sin in His creation with His children on earth as well seeing His  sons who rebelled against Him from the heavenly realm mixing together.  To see so much wickedness,  so  much violence and hatred towards each other must've just grieved Him  to the core.  It's a example to all of creation what sin produces.
Wickedness, hatred, death.  We all suffer and grieve  when we see violence and wickedness.

It also teaches Creation that just because you wipe everything off the face of the earth except a few that  it will spring up again in Noah and his sons.

I would say one of the major themes of Genesis 6:9 is that sin had been passed down to all man, including Noah and his sons.

> "There is no one righteous, not even one; Rom.  3:11

Sin could not be washed away from the earth when millions of people and creatures died in the flood.  It continued to live in man.

Prior to the flood men had no laws to  at least curb sin and it was shown that they just became exceedingly wicked and violent the longer they lived.  God shortened man's lifetime to 120 years.

> his days shall be 120 years.
> Genesis 6:3

The destructiveness of sin is clearly shown in the millions of people who had become so wicked, and violent they had to be wiped off the earth.

One major theme I would say is seeing the destructiveness of sin and especially when it's not controlled to some degree it causes great ruin.

As a sidenote we later see the Law cannot take away sin either.

There is only one solution to this dilemma and it begins with the Lamb of God.

> Behold, the Lamb of God, who is taking away the sin of the world; John 1:29

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the Flood Judgment was that God hoped to separate evil and start anew with Noah. In this sense, Noah was a "new Adam." This may be inferred from God's blessing to Noah, which echoes the blessing given to Adam in Gen. 1:

> So God blessed Noah and his sons, and said to them: “Be fruitful and
> multiply, and fill the earth. (Gen. 9:1)

So why did evil manifest again in Noah's family?

The text does not say exactly what God hoped to happen with Noah's family. But we can see the outcome. In the Garden of Eden, Adam and Eve had been naked an unashamed. Despite the Flood Judgment, the fallen nature of human beings manifested when Noah's son Ham reacted in shame to seeing Noah's nakedness. (Gen. 9:22-213) Worse still was Ham's act of spreading his attitude about Noah's nakedness to his brothers. Just as God grieved over the situation of humankind prior to the Flood, he now grieved over Noah's family. Having sworn not to judge the world again through another Flood, God would begin a new providence 10 generations later centered on the family of Abraham. Once the conditions had been established in the fulness of time, God would send the Messiah to Abraham's descendants.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose an analogy is liking cleaning/renovating a room or building.  If a room or building is sort of filled with dirt or completely ruined with walls, floors and furniture that is beyond repair then we could think of God's Flood recounted in Genesis 6-9 as being a complete "total deep cleaning"(for lack of a better phrase) / complete renovation of entire said room or building.

Even though God tells Noah in Genesis 9:11 that He will Never flood the world again in order to destory it, we can still continue elaborate on the analogy

> Genesis 9:11 New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 11 I establish My covenant with you; and all flesh shall never again
> be cut off by the water of the flood, neither shall there again be a
> flood to destroy the earth.”

Now let's elaborate on said analogy by saying that as time goes by, said room or building becomes dirty or has need of new renovation due to damage which can be compared to the account of ( Genesis 19:1-14 ) Sodom and Gomorrah's sin which chronologically happens after God's Flood recounted in Genesis 6-9.

> Genesis 19:1-14 New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 19 Now the two angels came to Sodom in the evening as Lot was sitting
> in the gate of Sodom. When Lot saw them, he rose to meet them and
> [a]bowed down with his face to the ground. 2 And he said, “Now behold,
> my lords, please turn aside into your servant’s house, and spend the
> night, and wash your feet; then you may rise early and go on your
> way.” They said however, “No, but we shall spend the night in the
> square.” 3 Yet he urged them strongly, so they turned aside to him and
> entered his house; and he prepared a feast  for them, and baked
> unleavened bread, and they ate. 4 Before they lay down, the men of the
> city, the men of Sodom, surrounded the house, both young and old, all
> the people  [b]from every quarter; 5 and they called to Lot and said
> to him, “Where are the men who came to you tonight? Bring them out to
> us that we may [c]have relations with them.”
> ...........more....scripture......
> .....more....scripture... 12 Then the two men said to Lot, “Whom else have you here? A son-in-law, and your sons, and your daughters,
> and whomever you have in the city, bring them out of the place; 13 for
> we are about to destroy this place, because their outcry has become so
> great before the Lord that the Lord has sent us to destroy it.” 14 Lot
> went out and spoke to his sons-in-law, who [l]were to marry his
> daughters, and said, “Up, get out of this place, for the Lord will
> destroy the city.” But he appeared to his sons-in-law [m]to be
> jesting.

God's Flood recounted in Genesis 6-9 ----analogical comparison--> "total deep cleaning" / complete renovation of entire said room or building

God's destruction of Sodom & Gomorrah Genesis 19:1-14 ----analogical comparison--> minor scrubbing of dirt / or doing some renovation of an isolated area in a room or building

Therefore, some of the major themes are:

-Sin is way too evil, wicked and horrendous that destruction of the world can **Not** be enough to end and/or pay for sin itself, and therefore, sin can Only be destroyed by  form of payment which is referenced in the following verses:

> John 3:16 New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 16 “For God so loved the world, that He gave His [a]only begotten Son,
> that whoever believes in Him shall not perish, but have eternal life.
>
> 1 John 2:2 New American Standard Bible 1995
>
> 2 and He Himself is the [a]propitiation for our sins; and not for ours
> only, but also for those of the whole world.

-LOL, To all the climate change/global warming activists / protesters in the world,  I suppose that both God's Flood recounted in Genesis 6-9 and  God's destruction of Sodom & Gomorrah in Genesis 19:1-14 are examples of how God uses natural disasters in order to make some sort of short-term redress / correcting of some sin in this world.

Comment: The evidence of Sodom and Gomorrah remains to this day.

Comment: @David Alright, evidence of Sodom and Gomorrah, therefore, I think that gives my answer more credibility and relevance.

Comment: If someone downvotes then please give the reasons